# How could i make a command block message when Zombie died?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a custom map in which I have a command block but I don't know how to make it display a message when a Zombie dies.

If anyone knows how to do that, it'd be great if you told me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do

```
/scoreboard objectives add Death dummy
```

Then run a repeat command block with this command:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Zombie] Death 1 {Health:0.0f}
```

And another repeat command block with

```
/testfor @e[type=Zombie,score_Death=1]
```

pointing into a conditional chain always active command block with

```
/tellraw @a ["",{"text":"A Zombie Has died!","color":"white"}]
```

or whatever you want the death message to be.

Comment: @user166681 @RudolfL.Jelínek This does **not** work. You cannot use the `@e` selector to target dead entities, which happens when their `Health` is 0.

Comment: Or have an objective that counts deaths, and when it is 1 trigger the command?

Comment: Auto-incrementing objectives do not work for non-player entities.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's impossible to do using just the vanilla Minecraft and a command block. However, you can count the number of zombies killed by each players by using the [Scoreboard](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard). It is a very complicated and complex tool to use and might be what you needed in the end.
For example, `scoreboard objectives add killZombie stat.killEntity.Zombie Zombies Killed` then `scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar killZombie` will show to everyone, to the right of their screen, the number of zombies killed by every players. Then, in a command block, you can use `/testfor @p[score_killZombie_min=10]` to see if a player killed at least 10 zombies.